# How to make UIScrollview with xCode 4.2 and storyboards

Tags: uiscrollview, ios5, xcode4.2, storyboard

I am new to iOS Development and am wondering how to put a scrollview in a storyboard, using Xcode 4.2. I want the content to be 1280 by 460. This code all works well, but when I go to wire up the outlet, there is no file's owner, so i'm stumped. Here is the code I have:

in the .h file-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

}

@end
```

and the .m, under viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1280,460)];
    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

If anyone could help me, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboards do not have a File's Owner.  You need to use the View Controller to connect the Outlets instead.  I.E. Drag to the View Controller in the same way you used to drag to the File's Owner.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. I just had to create a class for my view controller. I was trying to use files that were not part of a class that was a subclass of UIViewController.I had to create a new class, then copy the old code in and make my view controller's class that of the NEW files, and THEN wire up the outlets. I was changing the class to something that was not there. I then wired my outlet up to the scroll view I wanted. Thankfully, that part is finally over! Thanks for the suggestions, guys, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -5):

A good visual tutorial is in the current [Stanford CS193p course for iOS 5](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=480479762) in iTunes U.
This course works mainly with storyboards and they cover among other things `UIScrollViews`

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely watch that one.

Comment: answers that are simply links to external sites are poor answers. You can improve the answer by summarizing or describing the salient parts of the Stanford tutorial, retaining the link as further information.

Comment: Specially when you don't even point to the specific part of the course

Comment: And especially when those are do not contain written code out of the box and you have to dig in to see it